# Transforming a string in Ruby w/ `gsub` using an array of regexps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, binding, proc

I have a string, that I want to transform using Ruby's `gsub` and a TON of regexps and their resulting transformations in an array of arrays.

I like to do something like this:

```rb
MY_REGEXPS = [
  [ 
    /^(\d-\d:) (SINGLE|DOUBLE|TRIPLE)/, 
    proc { "#{$1} #{$2.capitalize}," }
  ],
  #....Many for regexp/transformation pairs
]

my_string = "0:0 SINGLE (Line Drive, 89XD)"

MY_REGEXPS.inject(my_string) do |str, regexp_pair|
  str.gsub(regexp_pair.first, &regexp_pair.last)
end
```

However, the proc is not bound to the context of the gsub match, so variables like `$1` and `$2` are not available.  I also confirm that if I just use the regexp/transformation in the process of a normal call to gsub, like:

```
my_string.gsub(/^(\d-\d:) (SINGLE|DOUBLE|TRIPLE)/) do
  "#{$1} #{$2.capitalize},"
end
```

the code works just fine.

Can anyone tell me a way for me to bind that proc to the context of the gsub so I can access `$1` and `$2`?

Thanks

Comment: The regex doesn't match the string: just changed `my_string = "0-0: SINGLE (Line Drive, 89XD)"` and it works for me :)

Comment: Some may refer to this as an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have become focused on the subject of your last sentence and have possibly lost track of your ultimate objective, which might be achieved in other ways. We all get sucked down that hole at times. It's certainly something to guard against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following or a variant would meet your needs.

```
MY_REGEXPS = [
  [ 
    /^(\p{L}+) (\d:\d) (SINGLE|DOUBLE|TRIPLE) \1/i,
    proc { |_,v2,v3| "#{v2} #{v3.capitalize}," }
  ],
]

my_string = "dog 1:2 single dog (Line Drive, 89XD)"

MY_REGEXPS.inject(my_string) do |s,(re,p)|
  p.call(*s.match(re).captures)
end
  #=> "1:2 Single,"
```

I've included capture group #1 `(\p{L}+)` (match one or more letters) to show how a capture group might be included that is not relevant to the proc calculation, but [MatchData#captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) can still be passed to the proc. (Capture group #1 is used here to ensure that the content of that capture group appears again at the specified location in the string (`\1`)).

Comment: Very clever and basically the same solution I ended up with, good to have some outside confirmation.  Thanks!